# Project window close stopped cascading close of subfolders

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I can't really point my finger on what version this changed, yet the problem is consistent, maybe i'm missing a shortcut to fix this, so I thought to post this here.

In project window, when I have a folder open, and then any subfolders open (no matter which depth), when I close the folder, it used to close all subfolders. It just doesn't anymore.

Any idea how to fix this? Or is this an issue that should be tracked?

Thanks,
Bud

Comment: WHat's you IDE version? Yes, I remember seeing such stuff, but I think it was reverted back (not 100% sure though, need to check deeper). It's working OK for me on latest stable PhpStorm 2018.2.5...

Comment: In any case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186081 ?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow [IDEA-186081](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186081) for updates.

Try enabling `async.project.view.collapse.tree.path.recursively` Registry key (**Help | Find action**, type `Registry...` to locate it) - does it help?